# How do i rotate an image animated on button click in WPF through C# code (Not XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, wpf-animation

I dont know if im approaching this wrong or if there is an error in my code.

And as i said above i would like to solve the problem through C# code and not in XAML.

I don't get any compiler errors it just does nothing.

XAML:

```
    <Button Content="Rotate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1007,637,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" Height="36" Width="51"/>
    <Image x:Name="Brett" Margin="0,-563,0,187" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Monopoly_Brett_bib.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" OpacityMask="White"></Image>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3, 0));
        Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
        storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, Brett);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));
        doubleAnimation.From = 0;
        doubleAnimation.To = -90;
        storyBoard.Begin();
        storyBoard.Completed += StoryBoard_Completed;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From =0,
            To = -90,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
        };
        Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        Brett.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform();

        storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, Brett);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Angle"));

        storyBoard.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. That's how I got it, I wanted a rotating settings image. I was using the 'mouse enter' event though. hope this helps:

```
 private void BtnSettings_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
      int angle = 270;
      SetImage.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(angle);            
 }
```

and during the mouse leave event, I reversed the angle (int angle=0)